# Ether wallet IOS app with testnet functionality

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

I'm trying to find an Ethereum wallet app on the apple app store to test my Dapp's QR code functionality but can't seem to find any wallet apps that support Ropsten. I've tried Ethers as they claim to do be able to do this but can't for the life of me see how to do it and think it might just not have been implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From their [github](https://github.com/ethers-io/EthersWallet-ios/issues/15):

> You cannot connect to a TestRPC, but you can use Ropsten, Rinkeby and Kovan testnets.
>
> To enable these networks, once you have the application installed, on your device go to https://ethers.io/app-link/#!debug and toggle the "enable testnet".
>
> Then when you create a new account, there will be an option in the right button of the navigation bar to choose the network you wish to have the account connect to.

It's strange that you can't do this in-app, but instead you need to install the app, switch to the browser, go to the url, and then open the link in the Ethers app.

But seems to work.

(btw thanks for telling about Ethers app, I found your question by Googling for a mobile app for connecting to testnets..)